# Android: Is that possible to make little bit near navigation drawer icon and text?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

In my application am creating navigation drawer.I don't want to customize menu using listview and all.But am stuck with navigation menu item and text alignment.I need to be little bit near.Please find the attached screenshot.Is that possible using with changing style.[image: Please look on to this]

Comment: try using negative margins.

Comment: Where i want to add?

Comment: to the textview

Answer (score 0):

you can override the default padding of `NavigationView` on **dimens.xml**

try to put this to your **dimens.xml**

```
<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_navigation_icon_padding">5dp</dimen>
```

Comment: and should i add anything in navigationview

Comment: no, you dont have to add anything to your NavigationView, that'll override dimen of all the NavigationView on your project